# Injecting fragment with activity reference

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have a class `DashboardActivity` with two fragments, A and B, in a viewpager. Each Fragment has its own `ViewModel`, `AViewModel` and `BViewModel`, respectively.

Now currently I'm creating a `Subcomponent` for the `DashboardActivity`, which binds both viewmodel instances and injects them into the fragments via `ContributesAndroidFragment`.

How could I create a Subcomponent per Fragment, so that dependencies requiring an activity (in this case `NavigationController`) could still be fullfilled? i.e. How can I create this subcomponent by providing the activity the fragment is being attached to?

Consider that these fragments could be added elsewhere in the app so the attaching activity could be different in runtime.

This is how I've done it:

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            ApplicationModule::class,
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            NetModule::class,
            ...
            ActivityBindings::class
        ]
)
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApp> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

ActivityBindings:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindings {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [DashboardModule::class])
    @PerActivity
    abstract fun dashboardModule(): DashboardActivity
    ...
}
```

DashboardModule:

```
@Module(includes = [CommonActivityModule::class])
abstract class DashboardModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsActivity(activity: DashboardActivity): AppCompatActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeFragmentA(): FragmentA

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributesFragmentB(): FragmentB


    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(BViewModel::class)
    @PerActivity
    internal abstract fun bViewModel(bViewModel: BViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AViewModel::class)
    @PerActivity
    internal abstract fun aViewModel(aViewModel: AViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

CommonActivityModule:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewContainerModule::class, ViewModelBuilder::class])
abstract class CommonActivityModule {

    @Binds
    @ForActivity
    abstract fun bindsContext(activity: AppCompatActivity): Context

    @Module
    companion object {

        @Provides
        @PerActivity
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideNavigationController(activity: AppCompatActivity) = NavigationController(activity)
    }
}
```

PS. I need to be able to inject more fragments from `fragmentA` and `fragmentB`, so they should also act as AndroidInjectors

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck. You have a component graph `App > Activity > Fragment` and your setup looks correct so that you can inject the activity in the fragments as well, basically it's everything you described. Could you clarify what isn't working as expected?

Comment: I can't figure out how to create a separate subcomponent for my fragments (a and b) that can also inject in subsequent fragments contained within these two... As it is right now A and B are injected by the activity so any dependency used by these two or the fragments within those has to be declared on the activity level. I want subcomponents per fragment and not per activity

Comment: I still don't quite follow. You declare your fragment subcomponents in the activity module (`@ContributesAndroidInjector .. FragmentA`), all you need to do is inject your fragment with its subcomponent. (And you can keep nesting fragments within fragments the same way you added those two fragments to your Activity component) What do you mean they are injected by the activity? Can you share the code how you create / inject your fragments?

Comment: I just use AndroidInjector.inject and AndroidSupportInjector.inject. Can you give an example on how to inject nested fragments?